# how to set ActiveMQ connection username and password through JNDI

Tags: activemq-classic, jndi, oozie

I am using Oozie, trying to enable its JMS notification feature.
I used following JNDI string to connect activeMQ broker

```
java.naming.factory.initial#org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory;
java.naming.provider.url#tcp://localhost:61616;
connectionFactoryNames#ConnectionFactory
```

Currently oozie server will throw exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: User name [null] or password is invalid.
```

However, I don't know how to append user/password info in above JNDI string. Can someone help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append "userName#foo;password#bar" in the JNDI string works for me finally

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting them from the URI using something like:

```
java.naming.provider.url#tcp://localhost:61616?jms.userName=foo&jms.password=bar;
```

The values could probably also be provided without the jms. prefix, as in some cases the code will strip them, it somewhat depends on which ConnectionFactory gets used and the path through the code to set those values, it seems that in JNDI the code might actually on use the non-prefixed versions.  Testing will win out and show which works.

Comment: userName#foo;password#bar

Answer (score 1):

`tcp://localhost:61616?user=foo;password=bar` working for me

Comment: Why is this preferred over e.g. `jms.userName`, as proposed in a previous, otherwise similar answer?